# How to convert nvarchar column written full-date name into a date format

Tags: typeconverter

**I have 2 varchar columns about the full date like  this :**

**input date, Output data**

19 October 2018 Friday

5 December 2018  Wednesday

1 January 2019 Tuesday

**I want to turn  into this:**

10/19/2018

12/5/2018

1/1/2019

Does anyone know how to do this?

Many Thanks

Comment: create you own parser I would say

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the day of the week text and then converting to date:

```
declare @str varchar(max)  = '19 October 2018 Friday'
select convert(date, left(@str, len(@str) - charindex(' ', reverse(@str)))) as dt
```

Comment: You are great dude. 
Many thanks. 
I realize that our date format is Turkish.
Like:
 
1 Şubat 2018 Pazartesi.

Can we do something  for  different counties Month name ???

Comment: Which SQL server are you using? Microsoft?

Comment: Yes I'm using microsoft SQL server 2016